# How to auto lookup & fill record if checkbox is checked in MS Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have 3 tables:

**Customers Table**

[image]

**Transactions Table**

[image]

**Delivery Table**

[image]

In the customers tables every customer has a delivery rate (based on their location).
What I am trying to accomplish is when I add an order to the transactions table, if the checkbox is checked it should automatically add new a record in the Delivery Table filling out the `customerID, & Date,` based on current transaction name & date & `DeliveryCharge` based on the delivery rate this customer has.

How do I accomplish that? Please Help!

NOTE: I am not sure if by making a separate Delivery Table like I did is the way to go in general. If you have a different/better way to add optional shipping charge with query, etc. Please let me know.

Comment: Might be able to do something with Data Macro but I've never used them. Build forms for user interface and code behind form. You don't associate Transactions and Delivery records. How do you verify the delivery charge is valid if it is not associated with any transaction record? Will each transaction have its own charge - transactions are not 'batched' into one delivery? Why not just record the delivery date and charge in the transaction record?

Answer (score 1):

First, a discussion about your table structure. Your Transactions table is using CustomerName instead of CustomerID. That will give you problems. In this case, it doesn't appear there is much difference between the Transactions and Delivery tables. Therefore I would recommend combining them. The only reason I would not is if you intend to split transactions into multiple deliveries. Finally, your Transactions table should not include the total price. Make another table like TransactionDetails that tracks the price of each product purchased and associates it with a single transaction number.

As for the rest of your question, you have a pretty broad approach question so I will give you a broad answer. One way you can do this is to use a form. VBA is absolutely capable of running the SQL queries you need, storing the values in variables, and then reusing them in an INSERT query.

I would recommend implementing it with a form that gets your user input and has a button to click that runs the required queries. Without more specific coding, I'm afraid you're not going to get much more feedback.